# C++ class Design with Inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance

```
class Base 
{
public:
    static int  GetType_S()
    {
        return 1;
    }
    virtual int GetType()
    {
        return GetType_S();
    }
};

class Son1 : public Base 
{
public:
    static int GetType_S()
    {
        return 2;
    }
    virtual int GetType()
    {
        return GetType_S();
    }
};
```

My Question is : When I need some other classes like "Son1,Son2..." ,every class should implement GetType and GetType_S function, This two functions is repeated.So How to design this classes gracefully to let son classes implement only one function?And It is best not to use macros.

Comment: Your example is not very clear, having a class holding an `int` and then having `GetType` return that `int` would be much easier and "graceful". Is there something specific you want to achieve?

Comment: Your question is not clear, you should try to reword.  As for concrete derived classes having to implement the base class functions, that is only true if the parent class function is pure virtual such as virtual int GetType() = 0; If the function is not pure virtual, and has a default implementation in the parent, the child does not have to reimplement it.

Comment: @GonenI Pure virtual function makes the base class an abstract class from which we can't create an object. Derived classes must implement a pure virtual function, this is required as there is no default behavior from the base class.  However, derived classes can choose whether to implement a non-virtual function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a class template that each `SonN` inherits from, which in turn inherits `Base`.

```
template <int Type>
class Middle : public Base 
{
public:
    static int  GetType_S()
    {
        return Type;
    }
    virtual int GetType()
    {
        return GetType_S();
    }
};

class Son1 : public Middle<2> {};

class Son2 : public Middle<3> {};

class Whatever : public Middle<42> {};
```

Or, if there is nothing else in those classes:

```
using Son1 = Middle<2>;
using Son2 = Middle<3>;
using Whatever = Middle<42>;
```